# After animation in an animation layer is done playing the character remains in the last position of said animation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

**DESCRIPTION**

I am learning to use Animation Layers. I created one with a mask so only the torso and head are affected. It has an empty state so that the animation isn't played first thing automatically, which transitions to a torso hit animation when a trigger is activated. The animation is set to `Additive` with weight of `1` as I want the the animation to be played with all of its intensity.

The animation works beautifully and when my character is shot in the torso it seemingly winces from the pain by bending its torso down while continuing to run or do stuff.

**PROBLEM**

After the animation is completed, the character remains with its torso bent down and continues running/doing stuff in that position instead of simply assuming the position of whichever animation is playing in the Base layer.

**WHAT I TRIED**

Fiddling with all of the settings visible in the image below, including "has exit time" and "interruption source", creating a transition back to the empty state and googling. Unfortunately, this is the full extent of my knowledge.

**SETTINGS**

[image]

**QUESTION**

How can I have the character revert back to the position of whichever animation is playing in the Base layer after the hit animation is played?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any transition back from `Torso hit` to `New State`.

Try adding one with

- `has exit time` = `true`
- `exit time` = 1

Like this (might want to adjust the duration of course)

[image]